# Slide the rest of the blocks when deleted

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I'm trying to have a smooth effect when deleting an element.
I want to add a transition when a block is deleted and bottom blocks goes up using a transition or a slide effect.

```js
const animateCSS = (element, animation, prefix = 'animate__') => {
  // We create a Promise and return it
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const animationName = `${prefix}${animation}`;
    const node = document.querySelector(element);

    node.classList.add(`${prefix}animated`, animationName);

    // When the animation ends, we clean the classes and resolve the Promise
    function handleAnimationEnd(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      node.classList.remove(`${prefix}animated`, animationName);
      resolve('Animation ended');
    }

    node.addEventListener('animationend', handleAnimationEnd, {once: true});
  });
}

function delete_comment(id_comment){
    console.log(id_comment);
    animateCSS('#comment_'+id_comment, 'fadeOut').then((message) => {
        $('#comment_'+id_comment).remove();
        //Slide the rest of the block
    });   
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".comment_tools" ).on( "click", function() {
      var get_id = this.id;
      delete_comment(get_id)
  });
});
```

```css
.comment_block{
    transition: all 1s;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 10px;
     display: inline-flex;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
     background: green;
}
 .comment_profil_section{
     width: 15%;
}
 .comment_content_section{
     width: 85%;
     padding-left: 10px;
}
 .comment_header{
     text-align: left 
}
 .comment_datetime{
     display: block;
     font-size: 12px;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     margin-top: -2px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .comment_message{
     text-align: left 
}
 .comment_user_picture{
     border-radius: 50%;
}
 .comment_user{
     font-weight: 400 
}
 .comment_tools{
     float: right;
}
 .comment_tools > .fa-pen{
     margin-right: 25px;
     color: #57CBCC;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .comment_tools > .fa-minus-circle{
     color: #CC5857;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .comment_tools > .fa-check{
     color: #57CBCC;
     cursor: pointer;
     margin-right: 25px;
}
 .comment_tools > .fa-times{
     color: #CC5857;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .loader_comment_block{
     position: absolute;
     right: 30px;
     display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
<div id="comment_section" style="text-align: center" class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
   <div id="comment_101" class="comment_block">
      <div class="loader_comment_block" id="loader_comment_block_101">
         <div class="loader-2 center"><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment_profil_section"><img width="40" height="40" class="comment_user_picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"></div>
      <div class="comment_content_section">
         <div class="comment_header"><span class="comment_user">USER</span><span class="comment_datetime">10/02/2021 à 15h53</span></div>
         <div class="comment_message">AAA</div>
         <div id="101" class="comment_tools">DELETE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="comment_100" class="comment_block">
      <div class="loader_comment_block" id="loader_comment_block_100">
         <div class="loader-2 center"><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment_profil_section"><img width="40" height="40" class="comment_user_picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"></div>
      <div class="comment_content_section">
         <div class="comment_header"><span class="comment_user">USER</span><span class="comment_datetime">10/02/2021 à 15h53</span></div>
         <div class="comment_message">BBB</div>
         <div id="100"  class="comment_tools">DELETE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="comment_99" class="comment_block">
      <div class="loader_comment_block" id="loader_comment_block_99">
         <div class="loader-2 center"><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment_profil_section"><img width="40" height="40" class="comment_user_picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"></div>
      <div class="comment_content_section">
         <div class="comment_header"><span class="comment_user">USER</span><span class="comment_datetime">10/02/2021 à 15h53</span></div>
         <div class="comment_message">CCC</div>
         <div id="99" class="comment_tools">DELETE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="comment_97" class="comment_block">
      <div class="loader_comment_block" id="loader_comment_block_97">
         <div class="loader-2 center"><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment_profil_section"><img width="40" height="40" class="comment_user_picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"></div>
      <div class="comment_content_section">
         <div class="comment_header"><span class="comment_user">USER</span><span class="comment_datetime">10/02/2021 à 15h33</span></div>
         <div class="comment_message">DDD</div>
         <div id="97" class="comment_tools">DELETE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="comment_73" class="comment_block">
      <div class="loader_comment_block" id="loader_comment_block_73">
         <div class="loader-2 center"><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment_profil_section"><img width="40" height="40" class="comment_user_picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"></div>
      <div class="comment_content_section">
         <div class="comment_header"><span class="comment_user">USER</span><span class="comment_datetime">10/02/2021 à 14h33</span></div>
         <div class="comment_message">EEE</div>
         <div id="73" class="comment_tools">DELETE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```

Comment: @executeable works for me

Comment: try animating `height` of the `fading block` from `current height` to `0` before removing the element `$('#comment_'+id_comment).remove();`

Comment: @user3732793 You have the slide effect ?

Comment: @kunalpanchal Doesn't work if I add `$("#comment_"+id_comment).css('height', '0');`

Comment: you mean slide away or slide down ? it slides down aufter klick on the delete button which feels kind of natural..What Do you want ?

Comment: @user3732793 the blocks under the deleted shoud slide to the new position, something like this http://jsfiddle.net/kMxqj/14/

Comment: ok sorry I have nothing handy. As you use jquery you could use the fadein as in the examples https://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried to animate and recreate somewhat like the link you have provided by adding `$(node).animate({height: 0,margin: 0, padding: 0}, 200);`
and also changed the css for:

```
.comment_block{ 
    display: flex; 
}
```

```js
const animateCSS = (element, animation, prefix = 'animate__') => {
  // We create a Promise and return it
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const animationName = `${prefix}${animation}`;
    const node = document.querySelector(element);

    node.classList.add(`${prefix}animated`, animationName);

    // When the animation ends, we clean the classes and resolve the Promise
    function handleAnimationEnd(event) {
      event.stopPropagation();
      node.classList.remove(`${prefix}animated`, animationName); 
      resolve('Animation ended');
    }
    $(node).animate({height: 0,margin: 0,position: "absolute", padding: 0}, 200); //HERE
    node.addEventListener('animationend',handleAnimationEnd , {once: true});
  });
}

function delete_comment(id_comment){
    console.log(id_comment);
    animateCSS('#comment_'+id_comment, 'fadeOut').then((message) => {
        $('#comment_'+id_comment).remove();
        //Slide the rest of the block
    });   
}
$( document ).ready(function() {
  $( ".comment_tools" ).on( "click", function() {
      var get_id = this.id;
      delete_comment(get_id)
  });
});
```

```css
.comment_block{
    transition: all 1s;
     width: 100%;
     padding: 10px;
     display: flex;
     margin-bottom: 5px;
     background: green;
}
 .comment_profil_section{
     width: 15%;
}
 .comment_content_section{
     width: 85%;
     padding-left: 10px;
}
 .comment_header{
     text-align: left 
}
 .comment_datetime{
     display: block;
     font-size: 12px;
     color: #FFFFFF;
     margin-top: -2px;
     margin-bottom: 10px;
}
 .comment_message{
     text-align: left 
}
 .comment_user_picture{
     border-radius: 50%;
}
 .comment_user{
     font-weight: 400 
}
 .comment_tools{
     float: right;
}
 .comment_tools > .fa-pen{
     margin-right: 25px;
     color: #57CBCC;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .comment_tools > .fa-minus-circle{
     color: #CC5857;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .comment_tools > .fa-check{
     color: #57CBCC;
     cursor: pointer;
     margin-right: 25px;
}
 .comment_tools > .fa-times{
     color: #CC5857;
     cursor: pointer;
}
 .loader_comment_block{
     position: absolute;
     right: 30px;
     display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/animate.css/4.1.1/animate.min.css"/>
<div id="comment_section" style="text-align: center" class="col-md-4 mx-auto">
   <div id="comment_101" class="comment_block">
      <div class="loader_comment_block" id="loader_comment_block_101">
         <div class="loader-2 center"><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment_profil_section"><img width="40" height="40" class="comment_user_picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"></div>
      <div class="comment_content_section">
         <div class="comment_header"><span class="comment_user">USER</span><span class="comment_datetime">10/02/2021 à 15h53</span></div>
         <div class="comment_message">AAA</div>
         <div id="101" class="comment_tools">DELETE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="comment_100" class="comment_block">
      <div class="loader_comment_block" id="loader_comment_block_100">
         <div class="loader-2 center"><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment_profil_section"><img width="40" height="40" class="comment_user_picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"></div>
      <div class="comment_content_section">
         <div class="comment_header"><span class="comment_user">USER</span><span class="comment_datetime">10/02/2021 à 15h53</span></div>
         <div class="comment_message">BBB</div>
         <div id="100"  class="comment_tools">DELETE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="comment_99" class="comment_block">
      <div class="loader_comment_block" id="loader_comment_block_99">
         <div class="loader-2 center"><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment_profil_section"><img width="40" height="40" class="comment_user_picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"></div>
      <div class="comment_content_section">
         <div class="comment_header"><span class="comment_user">USER</span><span class="comment_datetime">10/02/2021 à 15h53</span></div>
         <div class="comment_message">CCC</div>
         <div id="99" class="comment_tools">DELETE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="comment_97" class="comment_block">
      <div class="loader_comment_block" id="loader_comment_block_97">
         <div class="loader-2 center"><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment_profil_section"><img width="40" height="40" class="comment_user_picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"></div>
      <div class="comment_content_section">
         <div class="comment_header"><span class="comment_user">USER</span><span class="comment_datetime">10/02/2021 à 15h33</span></div>
         <div class="comment_message">DDD</div>
         <div id="97" class="comment_tools">DELETE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
   <div id="comment_73" class="comment_block">
      <div class="loader_comment_block" id="loader_comment_block_73">
         <div class="loader-2 center"><span></span></div>
      </div>
      <div class="comment_profil_section"><img width="40" height="40" class="comment_user_picture" src="https://cdn.pixabay.com/photo/2015/04/23/22/00/tree-736885__340.jpg"></div>
      <div class="comment_content_section">
         <div class="comment_header"><span class="comment_user">USER</span><span class="comment_datetime">10/02/2021 à 14h33</span></div>
         <div class="comment_message">EEE</div>
         <div id="73" class="comment_tools">DELETE</div>
      </div>
   </div>
</div>
```